# In the Starship's Mage series, where did the plotline with the Extravagant Voyage happen?

Tags: books, starships-mage

In book 13 of the Starship's Mage series, "Nemesis of Mars," there is a large timeskip and what feels like a recap of past events. One of these events is the capture of a facility by Roslyn Chambers that saved hundreds of thousands of workers; this was covered in book 12. There was also a subsequent fleet battle at Mackenzie by Admiral Medici; I think this was new but also it seemed straightforward.

But another incident mentioned was Mage-Queen Kiera Alexander's royal tour on *Extravagant Voyage*, and how that turned out. Too the best of my knowledge, nothing about this had been written before, but it felt too important - and too full of details - to just be a recap. An I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently only covered by the references within *Nemesis of Mars*, but Glynn Stewart appears to be planning to fill in the gap, going by the 'upcoming books' section of the latest novel:

> In Fall 2023, Kiera Alexander embarks on a solo adventure! In
> Mage-Queen’s Thief: A Starship’s Mage Novella, read the story of a
> kidnapping attempt gone wrong, set before the events of Nemesis of
> Mars.